# Does Irish Moss expire?

Tags: irish-moss

I've only bought one bag of Irish Moss in at least 2 years.  It's so cheap but is there really any need to replace it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Irish moss is a dried, dead product (seaweed), which if kept in a air-tight jar out of sunlight will last pretty much indefinitely. I'm using mine that I bought 4 years ago and the wort still clears nicely.

Some other anecdotal evidence, david_42, senior member on HBT [writes](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/irish-moss-shelf-life-199572/#post2324253)

> Well, I'm about half way though a 4 oz bag after 6 years. Seems to be doing the job still.

So I think you're fine with 2 year old moss.

Answer (score 4):

I have some that is about 16 years old.  I added it to a test sample of mead (the dregs that were left over after moving the must to a secondary fermenter). It clarified well and does not appear to affect the taste. I don't know how it will change with t