# Whirfloc shelf life and use

Tags: wort, finings, shelf-life

Making a batch and for the first time the recipe calls for a whirfloc tablet. From what I understand the tablet assists with settling the haze produced by proteins. I've read a half tablet to 5 gals. What is the expected shelf life? And is this something I should throw in on every batch I make in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've kept Whirlfloc for nearly a year and it was still fine.  I don't see why you couldn't keep it even longer. Although some people say you don't need it for dark beers, I disagree.  Even in a very dark beer you can see it it's clear or not.  I use it in every batch.  I don't think it's a deal breaker if you don't use it, but based on the times I've forgotten it, I do think it promotes better clearing.

Answer (score 2):

I use whirlfloc in pretty much every brew apart from some wheats where the protein haze is part of the style. Shelf life is about 2 years (see below.)

Even though the recipe calls for whirlfloc, you can use either whirlfloc or irish moss, both are kettle finings and contain the same active ingredient - kapa-carrageenan ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrageenan) lists other types and surprising uses.) I do 10 gallons mostly, so 1 whirlfloc tablet is the right dosage. When doing 5 gallons, I prefer the moss, since 1/2 tsp is easier to get than having to mess about with cutting whirlfloc tablets in half.

Irish moss has a shelf life of several years. (See related question [Does Irish Moss Expire?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6039/does-irish-moss-expire)). Given that whirlfloc is powdered, with a greater surface area, the shelf life can be expected to be reduced. I can't find the actual MSDS, but a reference is [here](http://www.brewingkb.com/homebrewing/Whirlfloc-vs-Irish-Moss-1791.html):

> In unopened original Kerry Bio-Science packaging, WHIRLFLOC BWS has a
>   shelf-life of 24 months from date of manufacture.

That's describing the sand-like powered form of whirlfloc. The compressed tablets I would guess kept in an opened, but airtight bag, would last about as long (tablet form reduces surface area, increasing shelf life, but the opened bag counter-acting that.) So, 2 years shelf-life seems reasonable.

(fwiw, I've just ordered a bag of 25 - I brew once a month, so that's a 2 year supply.)

EDIT: Here's a picture of how clear the wort will be after a good boil and kettle finings.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your info. I do mostly 5 gal batches. Sounds like I should have the stuff for a while. Will make it a practice to throw in for now on.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, throw some in - kettle finings really help clear up the wort, even if it wasn't very clear going into the kettle. Just be sure to have a vigorous boil and leave the wort to settle for 15-20 after flameout and you can end up with crystal clear wort.