# Does Protafloc expire?

Tags: irish-moss, finings, clarification, fining, copper

I'm using Protafloc Copper Finings for clearing the brew from proteins by adding it to the boil 15 minutes before the end of it. The product's made from red seaweed (Eucheuma Cottonii): http://www.brupaks.com/protafloc.htm.

According to what it says on the package, best before date of this product expires next month. I've read that a similar product - Irish Moss - almost never expires ([Does Irish Moss expire?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6039/does-irish-moss-expire)) How is it with Protafloc - should I worry about that expiry date, for how long would it still do its work? Could I extend the period by keeping it in the fridge or freezer? If it does start to lose its potency, is it OK to just increase the amount or are there some drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From these documents:  [PDF1](http://www.murphyandson.co.uk/datasheets/Data-Sheets2/Protofloc%20Powder.pdf) [PDF2](http://www.murphyandson.co.uk/datasheets/Data-Sheets2/Protafloc%20Tablets.pdf)

- Store in cool conditions, away from direct sunlight
- Keep containers sealed when not in use
- Maximum storage temperature - 30°C
- Recommended storage temperature - 10 to 15°C
- Minimum storage temperature - Not applicable
- The shelf life at the recommended storage temperature is 2 years from date of manufacture

Increasing the amount is NOT recommended (see the links above).

I am not sure what happens when it expires, but I might test it with a small batch of beer to ensure that it does not ruin the beer.

Otherwise, email the manufacturer and ask them.

Comment: I already had asked from the manufacturer, and they've also now replied, saying that the product will be OK for at least another 6 months, as long as I store it with the lid tightly on. Your research is a lot more detailed though, thanks loads!

Comment: Usually the "Best Before" is when the product reaches its half-life. After the half-life is reached, the manufacturer can't guarantee the freshness, so you have to be careful.